# Which Ubuntu distro to install on Dell Inspiron mini 10v with Intel Atom? Also to play Netflix?

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation

I have Dell Inspiron mini 10v with Intel Atom processor that was given to me. IT believe this has 1GB RAM.  Unsure if it is HDD or SSD but how do I find out?

It does not have CD.  However, I have usb 2.0 thumbdrive though.  For the performance to work, I d like to be able to use text editor, browse the surf and watch videos such as Netflix and Youtube.

Does anybody have instructions or recommendations?

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar

Answer (score 1):

for a lightweight and complete distro, check out Xubuntu or Lubuntu. Xubuntu has Xfce which is very fast and it has a very low memory footprint.  as is Lubuntu which comes with the "minimal" desktop that is LXDE.

take a look at [this post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions#Ubuntu-based) for a full list of Ubuntu-based distros.

Answer (score 1):

I run the hpMini with the Intel Atom processor. I use Lubuntu 14.04 for the 32 bit i386. It is my backup computer and seems to run fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) will best for you as it is lightest among the Ubuntu derivatives. You can use [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/), if you want a bit more functionality than Lubuntu.
If you want something visually appealing, then use [Elementary OS](https://elementary.io/), it looks a bit like OS X and is lighter than Unity.